# Install Oracle Database Extensions for .NET into VS2013

Tags: oracle11g, visual-studio-2013

How to install Oracle Database Extensions for .NET into VS2013.

[32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) 
with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)

Everytime I run this installer, it is always exclude Oracle Database Extensions for .NET. There is a reminder of **for upgrade only** in the description of the package installer.

```
Oracle Database Extensions for .NET 4 12.1.0.1.0 -- for upgrade only
Oracle Database Extensions for .NET 2.0 12.1.0.1.0 -- for upgrade only
```

So where should I get the installer for Oracle Database Extensions? Currently I using VS2013 Professional and Oracle database server 11g 64 bits.

I need that because of **Developing and Deploying a .NET Stored Procedure** using **Oracle Deployment Wizard**.

[Developing and Deploying a .NET Stored Procedure](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/devdeployproc/DevDepProc.htm?cid=4257&ssid=14405090636430#t2)

Inside this website, you can see the tutorial for VS2010 version.

**Additional**: I have to use Oracle 12c client 32bits because of VS2013 and Entity Framework.

**Additional**: I have ttied 64 bits, but my VS2013 still doesn't have Deploy option

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Well, this is guesswork:</strike>

Try installing ***Oracle 10g ODAC and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio .NET*** (very bottom of the downloads page) first, and then install the latest *for upgrade only* distribution.

Okay, here's an excerpt from [Oracle Database Extensions for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085095.html):

> This product is included with the Oracle Database on Windows installation. Further upgrades are installed as part of the Oracle Database Access Components (ODAC) releases, however Oracle Database Extensions for .NET must first be installed and configured before it can be upgraded.

Also, I found [Oracle® Database Extensions for .NET Developer's Guide 12c Release 1 (12.1) for Microsoft Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e18596/toc.htm). In it's [Installation and Configuration > Installation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e18596/install.htm#CHDBIBAB) section:

> **Before the first use of Oracle Database Extensions for .NET, do the following:**
>
> 1. Install Oracle Database 12c and either allow the installer to create the database for you, or install the database software only and use Database Configuration Assistant to create a database afterwards.
> 2. After installation and database creation, execute the following to enable Oracle Database Extensions for .NET.
>
>    ```
>       chopt enable ode_net
>    ```
> 3. Execute the following to create the Oracle Database Extensions for .NET windows service.
>
>    ```
>       oraclrctl -new
>    ```

***Bottom line:*** You have to install Oracle Database 12c to enjoy Oracle Database Extensions for .NET. It is meant to be a service running along with the database server, not in the client.